# POST request URL not working when used directly

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** a cinema site showtimes. When I observe the POST requests the site is using to retrieve the showtimes (https://www.majorcineplex.com/booking2/search_showtime/cinema=1), it is working correctly.

However when I use the POST request (https://www.majorcineplex.com/ajaxbooking/ajax_showtime) directly in the browser. It is showing me "There is no information for this show".

I find this weird as both were fired from the same Chrome browser but I am getting different results.

I offer my appreciations in advance for any help/advice provided.

**Update 29-May-2019**

Here is my code for the Scrapy spider.

Basically from the response, I am trying to retrieve a div element with the *class=book_st_contain*.

I am sure this div element is in the HTML as I have checked using the Chrome Dev Tools. However it is just not there when I run the spider.

```py
class SessionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'session'
    start_urls = [
      'https://www.majorcineplex.com/booking2/search_showtime/cinema=1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        f = open('response.txt', 'w')
        f.write(response.text)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Are you sure the requests send to the server are the same (including the headers)? You can use the F12 browser tools or a tool like Fiddler to investigate that.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, yea I am very sure the requests url were the same. I've checked with the Chrome Dev Tool and the actual URL (https://www.majorcineplex.com/booking2/search_showtime/cinema=1) was using the same POST request. (https://www.majorcineplex.com/ajaxbooking/ajax_showtime). The only difference was I was using the POST request directly on the Chrome brower. I tried CURL, REST-Client in VS Code but still not receiving the showtimes.

Comment: Hey @ShawnParker the basic debugging question should have your code, results you are getting and results you are expecting. Could you provide your scrapy code? At least the part that makes the `Request` object and maybe `settings.py` contents?

Comment: Hi @Granitosaurus, thank you for your reply.

I have updated the main question with my codes.

Appreciate your help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the headers and posted body matches the one you are seeing in your browsers devtools:

[image: chrome inspector tool showing major.com post request]

A scrapy spider to replicate this would look something like this:

```
class MySpider(spider):
    name = 'major'

    showtime_url = "https://www.majorcineplex.com/ajaxbooking/ajax_showtime"
    showtime_headers = {
        'Accept': "*/*",
        'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    }
    showtime_payload = "movie_text=&cinema_text={}".format

    def start_requests():
        # crawl cinemas with ids 1 to 10
        for cinema in range(1, 10):
            payload = self.showtime_payload(cinema)
            yield Request(
                self.showtime_url,
                headers=self.showtime_headers,
                body=payload,
                method='POST'
            )
```

Primarily you have to ensure `Content-Type` and `X-Requested-With` headers are present and match the values you see in your inspector.